# Android persisting deleted TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I am using Android Studio @ Ubuntu. I had an TextView at the UI that wasn't working and showing old values. For testing purposes, I tried to remove it of the UI at the style XML of the activity and, at the IDE preview worked fine.

But, for my surprise, the TextView keeps appearing **when I run the emulator**. I've alredy tried to delete the build folder and remake the projects. None worked.

Comment: Try manually deleting the application and then redeploying.

Comment: Try clean project,rebuild project or gradle sync

Comment: Try uninstalling the app. If not working, try on new emulator. If still persist then we need to look the code and xml.

Comment: Worked well uninstalling from the AVD and rebuilding. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. check taht instant run is disable on Android Studio.
2. clean your project.
3. run your App again.

## Check that you change correct layout.